# Clean local repository mirror

Tags: localrepository

Good morning,

I have a local mirror for 14.04, 16.04, 18.04 and 20.04 Ubuntu distributions. Is there a way to remove from local mirror packages for 14.04 and 16.04?

Best regards

Comment: More info needed what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a local mirror for distros listed above, it is arround 3T right now and I'd like to remove 2 distros from this mirror, 14.04 and 16.04. I no longer need those packages offline. I wonder if there is a way to remove them, or I need to purge whole mirror and just create new copy for 18.04 and 20.04

Comment: Which software do you use to create local mirror?

Comment: I have used apt-mirror

Comment: I am having the same problem right now.,